# Obteniendo datos de un insert en sql

Tags: javascript, mysql

En la tabla a la que estoy insertando tengo un ID autogenerado, lo que quiero hacer es obtener ese ID, pero no estoy seguro de cómo puedo hacerlo, y tengo que hacerlo de manera de que aunque el servidor reciba muchas peticiones no mezcle el ID de los equipos creados.

Este es mi código pero TeamId me sale vacío por lo que no se inserta el último statement.

```js
    async createTeam(req, res) {
        const { TeamName, CompanyId, UserId } = req.body;
    
        //All the logic for insert a new team
        try {
    
          const CreateTeam = await pool.query(
            `INSERT INTO teams (Name, CreatedBy, fkCompanyId, fkUserId)
                 VALUES ('${TeamName}', '${UserId}', '${CompanyId}', '${UserId}')`
          );
    
          //This logic can be better
          const TeamId = CreateTeam[0].TeamId
          console.log(TeamsId)
        
          const CreateTeamRelation = await pool.query(
            `INSERT INTO teamsrelation (fkUserId, fkTeamId)
                 VALUES ('${UserId}', '${TeamId}')`
          );
    
          res.json({
            code: 200,
            message: "Equipo creado correctamente",
            data: result,
          });
        } catch (error) {
          return res.json({
            code: 500,
            message: "Internal Server Error",
            error,
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: no se si esto te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112852/get-the-new-record-primary-key-id-from-mysql-insert-query

Comment: De que plataforma es este ejercicio?

Comment: agrega el código del backend